# Elasticsearch filter first record only on condition

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

In elasticsearch,
I have a table of data that have field customer_id and event_date, I want to count by each month but not all data, I want to filter out duplicated customer_id except first record (have min event date) before apply date historgrams, please help me to filter query.

This is my sample data:

```
"hits": [
            {
                "_index": "log_report",
                "_id": "5",
                "_score": 1.0,
                "_source": {
                    "created_at": "2021-08-23T02:36:10+00:00",
                    "created_by": -1,
                    "updated_at": "2021-08-23T02:36:10+00:00",
                    "updated_by": -1,
                    "is_deleted": false,
                    "account_id": 509,
                    "customer_id": 1961105,
                    "opened_at": "2021-08-23T02:36:10+00:00",
                    "id": 5
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "log_report",
                "_id": "11",
                "_score": 1.0,
                "_source": {
                    "created_at": "2021-08-23T02:37:26+00:00",
                    "created_by": -1,
                    "updated_at": "2021-08-23T02:37:26+00:00",
                    "updated_by": -1,
                    "is_deleted": false,
                    "account_id": 509,
                    "customer_id": 1961105,
                    "opened_at": "2021-08-23T02:37:26+00:00",
                    "id": 11
                }
            },
            ...
       ]
```

I have field `customer_id` and `created_at`, customer_id value can have same value in multiple records, but I just want work with first record foreach customer_id

Comment: Can you please add more details like sample data, what is expected result, what you have tried till now, what issue you are facing etc.. it will help us to understand question better and help you.

Comment: I updated my question. The main purpose I want to do is the chart on kibana, this data is log of user open app, but I just want to show data of download app (first times user open app).

Answer (score 1):

```
{
  "sort": [
    {
      "created_at": {
        "order": "asc",
        "unmapped_type": "date"
      }
    }
  ],
  "collapse": {
    "field": "customer_id"
  }
}
```

try this